# Convert INT to TIME using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have converted a feed's published date "pubDate" to integer using JS. 
Here is the code I used for it.

```
function timetoint(date){
    var date = new Date(date);
    return Math.round(date.getTime()/1000);
}
```

Now I need to convert the result of the above function back to a time format.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor :

```
 var date = new Date(time*1000);
```

Comment: is there a way to make this more pretty? Like in prettyTime? "1 minute ago, 1 hour ago, 2 days ago" ???

Comment: If you want pretty printing, parsing, and other time related functions, my advise is to use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).